# How much should you shift fragment energies to create an energy level diagram?

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, formation-energy

I am creating an energy level diagram for the orbitals of [XeF₅] - molecule produced by two fragments: [Xe] 4+ and [F₅] 5-. There is a very large energy difference between the two fragments, so I would like to shift the energy of each fragment orbital to make a cleaner energy level diagram. The original idea for shifting the fragments was to shift the energy of each fragment orbital *E* by the total energy of the other fragment *V*:

$E_{frag1}+V_{frag2}$

$E_{frag2}+V_{frag1}$

The problem is this energy shift is huge and I do not believe it is the best way to shift the fragment orbitals. I have not found many resources on properly shifting the energy of the fragment orbitals to make an energy level diagram, and I was wondering if there is any other (if any) systematic way of doing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have experience on this, but is it possible to not shift the energies, but add a break in the y axis, so that the correct energies of all orbitals are displayed and the splittings between the orbitals remain clearly visible?

Comment: I would recommend that you use CACAO (It's a fairly old program from Prof. Hoffmann's group). It will allow you to define the fragments and generate the energy level diagram.